# ggmap, ggimage... - Saving and loading maps in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, loading, gis, ggmap

In my current R project I'm working with the `ggmap` package to download and display maps. 
What bothers me is that you need internet access to load maps from google etc.
I'd like to load a map from the internet and save it so I can work offline as well. An ideal solution should minimize the amount of code between `get_map()` (or a related command) and using the saved map within `ggmap()` (or a related command).

I know already that `get_map()` has a `filename` attribute to save maps as an image, and I also know the `ggimage()` method (I've never actually worked with it, though.)

**Is there a simple way to save such a map, or are these two the best tools available - and if so, how can I use them effectively?**

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same question after waiting for the same maps to load dozens of times per run.

You can save any object in R, but it took me a little while to figure out the nuances of saving a map inside of a function.  Here's what I came up with -- would love to see if there are improvements that could be made.

The function looks for a Locale string (essentially something to name the map), coordinates, and zoom level. The function then looks to see if the map already exists as a saved file and loads it if it does.  If the map doesn't exist on the disk, it is downloaded from Google and then saves it to a file.

No tricks to loading it from a file, but I found that if I didn't specify `.GlobalEnv` in the assign function before saving the map object to disk, that R would faithfully load into into the wrong environment.

```
load.map <- function(Locale, Lon, Lat, MapZoom){
  MapName <- paste("Map", gsub(" ", "", Locale), MapZoom, sep = "")

  FileName <- paste(MapName,".RData", sep = "")
  if (file.exists(FileName) & ReloadMaps == 0)
  {
    load(FileName, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  } else 
  {
    Map <- get_googlemap(center=c(lon = Lon, lat = Lat), zoom=MapZoom, scale = 2,
        size = c(640, 640), maptype = "roadmap", color = "color", format = "png8")
    assign(MapName, Map,  envir = .GlobalEnv)
    save(list = MapName, file = FileName, envir = .GlobalEnv)
  }  
}
```